# Removing ChrW and space from cells in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that should remove all the non-printable characters and trim all space in the cells but it's not doing on all `selected` cells for some reason.

```
  Sub removeSpace()

    Dim rngremovespace As Range
    Dim CellChecker As Range

    Set rngremovespace = Selection

      rngremovespace.Columns.Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:=Chr(32), _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False

         For Each CellChecker In rngremovespace.Columns

            CellChecker.Value = Application.Trim(CellChecker.Value)
      CellChecker.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(CellChecker.Value)

     Next CellChecker
    Set rngremovespace = Nothing


  End Sub
```

Comment: Does the code run, but not do what you are expecting?  Or does it crash out?  (I would have expected the `Clean` of a column (using `WorksheetFunction.Clean`) to crash, but you don't mention any errors, so maybe I am reading the code wrong.)

Comment: @YowE3K It crashes if there is no `On Error Resume Next` statement give me run time error 13 and don't understand why.

Comment: If you are getting errors, I would recommend (a) using `rngremovespace.Replace` instead of `rngremovespace.Columns.Replace` (b1) using `For Each CellChecker In rngremovespace.Columns.Cells` instead of `For Each CellChecker In rngremovespace.Columns` so that it processes each cell rather than each column or (b2) using `Application.Clean` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean`

Comment: Which line gives the error?  (And "It crashes if there is no On Error Resume Next statement " is probably the same as saying "It crashes" - the `On Error` just says to continue processing if it crashes.)

Comment: @YowE3K The line that you mention above `CellChecker.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(CellChecker.Value)`

Comment: What cells are you selecting before running the code?  (I.e. is it a continuous range, or are they various cells in several locations?)

Comment: @YowE3K there 4 columns that i need to remove space and ChrW but i just selected 10 rows to see if it works so it's 10 rows by 4 columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Sub removeSpace()
    Dim rngremovespace As Range
    Dim CellChecker As Range

    Set rngremovespace = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)

    rngremovespace.Replace What:=Chr(160), _
                           Replacement:=Chr(32), _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                           MatchCase:=False

    For Each CellChecker In rngremovespace.Cells
        CellChecker.Value = Application.Trim(CellChecker.Value)
        CellChecker.Value = Application.Clean(CellChecker.Value)
    Next CellChecker

    Set rngremovespace = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above code avoids any references to `Columns`, and just works solely on the cells selected by the user.  If an entire column needs to be processed, that can be selected by the user, but the `Intersect` will ensure that only used cells will be processed.

The inclusion of `.Cells` in `For Each CellChecker In rngremovespace.Cells` ensures that any discontinuous cell ranges that have been selected will not cause the `For Each` to process each "area", but will instead process each cell separately.

Comment: Tried the above and now gives run time error 1004 on the `Application.Clean` - invalid number of arguments.

Comment: @QuickSilver - try the code I have pasted into my answer now

Answer (score 0):

Hey to remove all non printable characters as well as Trim please use this command line with your code,,

cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(cell.Value)

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the range to be treated seems imprecise. Try this way:-

```
Sub removeSpace()

    Dim rngremovespace As Range
    Dim CellChecker As Range

    With Selection
        Set rngremovespace = Range(Columns(.Column), Columns(.Column + .Columns.Count))
    End With
      rngremovespace.Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:=Chr(32), _
                             LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                             MatchCase:=False

    For Each CellChecker In rngremovespace
        CellChecker.Value = Application.Trim(CellChecker.Value)
        CellChecker.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(CellChecker.Value)
    Next CellChecker
    Set rngremovespace = Nothing
  End Sub
```

Comment: Tried and still gives the same run time error 13 on the line `CellChecker.Value = Application.Trim(CellChecker.Value)` can't work out why though.

Comment: @QuickSilver - is it the `Application.Trim` causing the error, or the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean`?

Comment: @YowE3K It's the `Application.Trim` that throws on error 13

Comment: @QuickSilver - try changing Variatus' code to use `For Each CellChecker In rngremovespace.Cells` (sometimes the `Each` in a range object will not refer to a cell, it might refer to an area, or a column)

Comment: FWIW - If `Selection.Address` is `$B$2,$B$3,$D$8,$H$8`, then `Selection.Columns.Count` is 1, so you would be setting `rngremovespace` to be `B:C`..

Comment: @YowE3K Tried with the `For Each CellChecker In rngremovespace.Cells` but the only problem with this is that it's really slow takes too much time to process.

Comment: @QuickSilver That will be slow because Variatus' code is selecting the entire columns (so 1048756 rows x 5 columns based on your 10 rows x 4 columns input).  But if that is working, even slowly, we can fix that easily.